# Centroid of semi-circle using weighted avarage.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, centroid

let the centroid be the  point $(x_c,y_c)$

where $$x_c = \frac{\int x ds}{\int ds}$$
$$y_c = \frac{\int y  ds}{\int ds}$$

Find the centroid of the semicircle $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$,  where $y >= 0  $
I was trying:
$$ y = \sqrt{a^2-x^2}$$
$$y' = \frac{-x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$$
$$ds = \sqrt{1 + (\frac{-x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}})^2}dx$$
$$y_c = \frac{\int_{-a}^a adx}{\int_{-a}^a \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx} = 1$$

which is wrong What did I get wrong?

Comment: $$ {\int_{-a}^a \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}} =a \times arcsin (\frac {x}{a})$$     denominator of last line $x_c$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $ds=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\,dx$, your last line should be
$$y_c = \frac{\int_{-a}^a \color{blue}{a}\,dx}{\int_{-a}^a \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\,dx}
=\frac{2a^2}{a[\arcsin(x/a)]_{-a}^a}=\frac{2a^2}{\pi a}=\frac{2a}{\pi}.$$
As regards the $x$- coordinate, we have that
$$x_c = \frac{\int_{-a}^a \frac{ax}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\,dx}{\int_{-a}^a \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\,dx}=0$$
because the integrand at the numerator is odd and the interval is symmetric with respect to $0$.

P.S. In polar coordinates the computation is easier:
$$y_c = \frac{\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} a\sin(\theta)\,a d\theta}{\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} ad\theta}
=\frac{2a^2}{a\pi}=\frac{2a}{\pi}.$$

P.P.S. Letting $x=a\sin(\theta)$ then $dx=a\cos(\theta)\,d\theta$ and
$$\int_{-a}^a \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\,dx
=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{a}{a\cos(\theta)}\,a\cos(\theta)\,d\theta=a\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}d\theta=\pi a.$$

Comment: can you help me with the answer is undefined in the x coord or the centroid a ln goes to infinity

Comment: why the using $x  = asin\theta$ did not work out?

Comment: I mean $x = asin\theta $ to get the denominator $acos\theta$ trig substitution

Comment: is that method valid?  because eq is in the form $cos =\sqrt{1^2-sen^2x}$

Comment: what happen in the limits of integration?

Comment: $asin(-a) = -\pi/2 $ what are the steps here

Comment: $-a=a\cdot \sin(\theta)\implies \sin(\theta)=-1\implies \theta=-\pi/2$

Comment: thank great answer

Answer (score 2):

An easier approach is direct integraiton by polar coordinates change. Take $x=a\cos t,$ and $y=a\sin t$, for $t\in(0,\pi)$. Then $$x_c=\frac{\int_0^\pi a\ cos t dt}{\int_0^\pi adt}=\frac{0}{\pi a}=0,$$ and $$y_c= \frac{\int_0^\pi a^2\sin t dt}{\int_0^\pi adt}=\frac{2 a}{\pi}$$

Comment: The proposer is asking about the centroid of the semicircle, not the semidisc!

Comment: Thanks for the observation. Edited it